# Using a user-defined command to align cells in a NiceTabular environment (nicematrix package)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, nicematrix

I am typing a report in which I handle big tables using the NiceTabular environment to display data tables.
I would like to be able to set the alignment (l, c or r) of a given set of cells/blocks at the compilation (to allow the user to change them easily), and to have the other ones keeping a given alignment. Of course, at each compilation, I could go and change manually each one of the alignment commands in each of the block I want to change the alignment of. But my tables are pretty big, and that would take ages whenever I would like to change the alignment of these cells.

Hence, my idea would be to define a command \MyAlignment that would apply to some cells/blocks only:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand{\MyAlignment}{r}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}
    \Block[r]{1-1}{11} & \Block[\MyAlignment]{1-2}{12} & & 14 \\
    \Block[\MyAlignment]{2-1}{23} & \Block[r]{1-2}{22} & & 24 \\
    & 32 & 33 & 34 \\
    41 & 42 & \Block[\MyAlignment]{1-2}{43} &
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

However, when I try to compile this, the compiler returns "The key '\MyAlignment' is unknown for the command \Block. If you go on, it will be ignored".
I tried to use \def, \edef, \xdef and \gdef instead of \newcommand, it does not change anything.

Would you have any idea about whether it is possible to do that, and how to? I generally find answers to all of my questions on StackExchange, but this time, although I tried my best, I did not find any topic already tackling this question around.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution by defining a new command `\MyBlock`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand{\MyAlignment}{r}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \MyBlock } { O { } }
  { \use:x { \exp_not:N \Block [ #1 ] } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}
    \MyBlock[r]{1-1}{11} & \MyBlock[\MyAlignment]{1-2}{12} & & 14 \\
    \MyBlock[\MyAlignment]{2-1}{23} & \MyBlock[r]{1-2}{22} & & 24 \\
    & 32 & 33 & 34 \\
    41 & 42 & \MyBlock[\MyAlignment]{1-2}{43} &
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works just great - or, rather, merci beaucoup from un bayonnais!

Comment: For my own curiosity, do you know why my original code was not functioning properly?

Comment: Because there is no expansion (in the TeX sens) of the content of the first argument of `\Block` (that is to say the argument between `[` and `]`) before passing it to the keys parser. TeX is *not* a functionnal programmation langage: the arguments are not evaluated systematically before passing them to the function as usual in classical programming langages. The command `use:x` I have put does that expansion.